# SQL query works with variable but not with literal

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a user-defined table-valued function in SQL Server with name `dbo.GetBillsByDate` that accepts one date parameter `@dateOf`.

The function returns successfully for all dates in October of 2015 except for 2015 October 14. The exceptional date causes a divide by zero error and also returns a warning. Here is the exact text:

```
Divide by zero error encountered.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
```

That the function runs on every date besides the 14th is confusing to me, but I've found that when I use a variable to pass in the data the function will return successfully. This causes more confusion.

So:

```
select * from GetBillsByDate('10/14/2015');
```

returns an error, and:

```
declare @dateOf date;
set @dateOf = '10/14/2015';
select * from GetBillsByDate(@dateOf);
```

does not.

Any insight?

Edit: Full body of `dbo.GetBillsByDate`

```
create function [dbo].[GetBillsByDate](@dateOf date)
returns table as
return
select propertyID                              PropertyCode, 
       billDate                                DateOf, 
       accountNum                              AccountNumber, 
       address1                                Address1, 
       address2                                Address2,
       dateadd(day, 1-day(@dateOf), @dateOf)   DatePosted,
       glcode                                  LedgerCode, 
       currMonthPostTotal                      AmountPosted

from AccruedBills

where convert(date, dateCreated) = @dateOf 
      and 
      startDate < endDate 
      and 
      billTotal >= 0 
      and 
      currMonthPostTotal<>0
union
select propertyID, 
       billDate, 
       accountNum, 
       address1, 
       address2, 
       dateadd(day, 1, dateadd(month, -1, dateadd(day, 1-day(@dateOf), @dateOf))),
       glcode, 
       prevMonthPostTotal

from AccruedBills

where convert(date, dateCreated) = @dateOf
      and
      prevMonthPostTotal<>0 
      and 
      startDate < endDate 
      and 
      billTotal >= 0
union
select propertyID, 
       billDate, 
       accountNum, 
       address1, 
       address2, 
       dateadd(day, 1, dateadd(month, -1, dateadd(day, 1, dateadd(month, -1, dateadd(day, 1-day(@dateOf), @dateOf))))),
       glcode, 
       remaMonthPostTotal

from AccruedBills

where convert(date, dateCreated) = @dateOf
      and
      remaMonthPostTotal<>0 
      and 
      startDate < endDate 
      and 
      billTotal >= 0
```

AccruedBills is a view. The query:

```
select * from AccruedBills where convert(date, dateCreated) = '20151014'
```

returns successfully.

Comment: You need to show the body of the GetBillsByDate function.

Comment: Does this return an error: declare @ dateOf varchar(10);
set @ dateOf = '10/14/2015';
select * from GetBillsByDate(@ dateOf)

Comment: You should use the ANSI standard for date strings. 2015-10-14

Comment: @TheTTGGuy It does not return an error.

Comment: @MattGibson It returns the same error.

Comment: I suspect there is something else going on in the query.  I find it hard to believe that the date is causing this.  Can you post the entire function?

Comment: Yeah, let's see at least the start of the declaration of the function, including the parameter, but preferably the whole thing. (Also, what result do you get from `select @@LANGUAGE`?)

Comment: @MattGibson See edit. `select @@LANGUAGE` returns `us_english`.

Comment: @SeanLange See edit.

Comment: I don't see how that error could come from that. Did you try using ANSI style date format?

Comment: I expect the error would have to be coming from this line `convert(date, dateCreated) = @dateOf`.  Can you show us the explain plan for the query using a variable and the query using the string directly?  I'm guessing `convert(date, dateCreated)` causes the error for some of your data, but it gets skipped depending on how the query is run.  Because you are querying the view, the problem most likely is inside of that (so you need to show us the body of the view as well).

Comment: What type is the column `dateCreated`?

Comment: @MattGibson `dateCreated` is a datetime column.

Comment: @SeanLange Incidentally, I know we're talking dates here rather than datetimes, but I generally find the non-hyphenated format ('20151014') safer. For example, try `SET LANGUAGE italian;
SELECT CAST('2015-10-14' AS DATETIME);`...

Comment: @Affecd To elaborate, every time sql-server runs a query that references a view, its query optimizer may run it in a different order.  What you're finding here is that for some reason this specific query is identifying a problem within your view definition that needs to be adjusted.  Alternatively, if you don't have access to the view, you could initially select it into a temp table to fix the problem.

Comment: Do you see any errors if you simply issue `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM AccruedBills`? (The `DISTINCT` should force the server to evaluate all rows before even passing them back to the client, as it'll have to do that to look for possible duplicates.)

Comment: @MattGibson The `DISTINCT` query returns all rows successfully.

Comment: My guess is that changing `convert(date, dateCreated) = @dateOf`into `dateCreated>= @dateOf and dateCreated < dateadd(day, 1, @dateOf)` to be SARGable and most likely you don't end up reading the row that causes the problem from the view

Comment: @JamesZ That's a sensible change, but it doesn't mean that this won't fall over for a different date parameter in the future, right? (Also, as my suggested test of `SELECT DISTINCT *` from the view didn't fall over, I'm still thinking there's something I can't explain going on here...)

Comment: @JamesZ The updated function returns the same error.

Comment: @MattGibson Yes even being SARGable it will fail for divide by zero

Comment: @MattGibson Selecting `DISTINCT *` isn't going to show us the problem because the query optimizer is still executing in the order that filters out the problem row.  For some reason the specific query generated by using the input string causes it to adjust its filters into an order that causes the error.  We need the actual view to know which row causes the problem.  Looking at the two different explain plans could help point us in the right direction.

Comment: Can you post the code for the view? I know we're a long way down the rabbithole here already, but there's nothing I can spot in any of your existing code that could cause a division by zero.

Comment: @AdamMartin By explicitly checking for divide by 0s during divison in the view, the function works. I filter 0s out of the divisor column earlier in the view, however, it seems the CTEs I am using to achieve my result are not an ideal solution. I think what you were saying was correct about the view not being consistently evaluated.

Comment: @AdamMartin Yup, good catch. Sometimes it takes me a while to remember how view optimisation works!

Answer (score 1):

Problem found in the `AccruedBills` view. The view uses sequential CTEs that build upon each previous CTE. Two of the queries contain a divide operation. Before these expressions are reached, however, I filter out 0s that would be contained in the divisor column. It seems that what @AdamMartin was saying was the cause. The view was not being evaluated in the order specified each time it was evaluated. By explicitly checking the divisions for divide by 0s, the query completes successfully.

Comment: Yeah, I've had to deal with this a couple of times;  it's just your query optimizer taking a different path for some reason.  Remember if re-factoring is ever an issue, using a temp table should be a workaround if the view compiles fine when called on its own.